# Dialogflow cannot test on slack anymore?

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I got this error every time I try to click 'test in slack' in the Dialogflow Integration:
**Test bot activation error: undefined**
I don't know what happened here. It works like two weeks ago and I didn't change anything. Is it just me or everyone?

Comment: Please be more specific by adding the code and configuration that is no longer working. In general question that might be bugs in existing frameworks are better addressed directly to the framework creator.

Comment: I've got the same error. It just stopped working from yesterday. So I tried to re-activate "Dialogflow Bot", an error occurs with the same error message that you've described.

Comment: Yesterday I tried to make bot public on slack, and it works fine. Maybe there's some issues for fast testing I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to Test integration with Slack today and looks like it starts to work again. Shutdown current test bot if possible and do OAuth again to see if the test @Dialogflow Bot comes back.